# AWS SES - Stuck on domain verification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-lightsail

my domain verification is stuck and I can not resolve it.

I am running Django Lightsail instance with specific 4 nameservers and I have a feeling this is the underlying issue.

For example, when I create new hosted zone, it creates one with different 4 nameservers, and I can change it later on, but it doesn't improve the verification. If that's the problem at all.

Thanks

Comment: Do you follow this guide? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domain-procedure.html If you have got to the point where you put the generated records to your domain, how did you do it? Where is the domain hosted? On your DNS servers or do you have some other provider?

Comment: i did follow this and checked a lot of other docs. My domain is hosted on Route53 so there's option to use that,  I tried that, then I even tried manually, and nothing.. I have no idea anymore and they are totally ignoring me so I should find different option how to get custom email domain

Comment: So you added the TXT record in route53 manually or you used the option from docs: "If Route 53 provides the DNS service for the domain that you're verifying, and you're signed in to the AWS Management Console under the same account that you use for Route 53, then Amazon SES gives you the option of updating your DNS server immediately...". Still the verification did not finish, is it correct? You do have the nameservers set by your registrar? Do you see the records with something like https://serverfault.com/questions/174054/list-txt-records-for-a-domain-with-windows-nslookup ?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and helping me out, I have solved it already. The problem was, I had to set all these records (TXT, CNAME) also in my Django Lightsail instance - no where is this mentioned. I am learning AWS the hard way. Been deploying my app for quite some time now.